# How to prove that a length is equal to the inradius of a triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, fractions

$D$ is the midpoint of the side $BC$ of the triangle $ABC$. The line joining $D$ and the incentre $I$ of the triangle intersects altitude $AA'$ at the point $P$.

Prove that the length of $AP$ is equal to the radius of the incircle of the triangle..

[image: image of triangle]

Comment: It might be worth including an image here, rather than attempting to describe it. You can click edit on your question and then upload an image from your computer by clicking the picture of a mountain in the bar along the top of the answer box

Comment: Drawing tip: [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/geometry).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $E$ be a tangency point with side $BC$ and  let $c>b$.

Hence, 
$$DE=BE-BD=\frac{a+c-b}{2}-\frac{a}{2}=\frac{c-b}{2},$$
$$BA_1=c\cos\beta=c\cdot\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ac}=\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2a}.$$
Thus, $$DA_1=BA_1-BD=\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2a}-\frac{a}{2}=\frac{c^2-b^2}{2a}.$$
Now, since $\Delta DIE\sim\Delta DPA_1,$ we obtain:
$$\frac{PA_1}{IE}=\frac{DA_1}{AE}$$ or
$$\frac{PA_1}{r}=\frac{\frac{c^2-b^2}{2a}}{\frac{c-b}{2}}$$ or
$$PA_1=\frac{r(b+c)}{a}.$$
In another hand, $$S_{\Delta ABC}=pr=\frac{(a+b+c)r}{2}=\frac{1}{2}ah_a.$$
Thus, $$AA_1=h_a=\frac{(a+b+c)r}{a},$$
which gives $$AP=AA_1-PA_1=\frac{(a+b+c)r}{a}-\frac{(b+c)r}{a}=r$$
and we are done!

Comment: What does a tangent Point mean?

Comment: @saisanjeev It's the common point of our circle and side $BC$. It's tangency point.